# Not able to call a method from InfoWindow in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am trying to call a method on click of an element. The HTML is stored in a variable. It looks like below:

```
var cont = '<div class="infocontent" onClick="clickPoly('+index +')" style="width:100px;" >View More</div>';

const clickPoly = (index) => {
   var square = coordinates[index];
  
   if(square != undefined){
      square.dispatchEvent('click');
   }
}
```

clickPoly() should be called onclick of html above. But when I click on "View More", it shows "clickPoly is not defined".

Basically, I am showing multiple polygons on google map and on hover of each polygon I am showing infowindow. In infoWindow I need to show "View More" button and show relevant content.

**You can see full code** [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-kilby-7qi8z?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You need to use JSX. `var cont = <div ...>...</div>;` (also, a codesandbox should actually be a [mre], that's the point of it)

Comment: @ChrisG Can you explain how?
Thank you!

Comment: This is not a React code.

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets You can see the complete code here. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-kilby-7qi8z?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clickPoly` needs to be defined on window.

```
window.clickPoly = (index) => {
  var square = coordinates[index];

  if (square != undefined) {
    square.dispatchEvent("click");
  }
};
```

alternatively, pass an HTMLElement to `infowindow.setContent(element)` and add the event in your component

```js
var cont = '<div class="infocontent2" data-inx="'+index+'" onClick="clickPoly('+index +')" style="width:100px;" >View More</div>';
```

becomes

```js
const cont = document.createElement('div').
cont.classList.add('infocontent2');
cont.addEventListener(() => clickPoly(index));
// add aria-label
cont.style.width = '100px';
cont.innerText = 'View More'
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks!